# Fetching data in NextJS using getServerSideProps returns Promise {<pending>}

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to fetch data in NextJS using getServerSideProps inside my component but it only returns **Promise {}**. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
const MyHomeComponent = () =>{
    const router = useRouter();

    const getServerSideProps = async () => {
      const data = await graphqlClient.query({query:GET_DATA, variables:{
        userId: Number(router.query.userId),
        tagIds: router.query.tagIds,
      }})
    return data.data.userDetails;
  };
  console.log(getServerSideProps()) <------------ console logs Promise {<pending>}

 return(
  <div>
    //Need to pass the fetched data here
  </div>
)
}
```

How can I display the fetched data inside my component?

Comment: You need to add the function getServerSideProps outside the component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getServerSideProps` should be outside the component. Returned data from the `getServerSideProps` function can be accessed within the component.

```
function Page({ data }) {
  // Render data...
}

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const data = await graphqlClient.query({query:GET_DATA, variables:{
    userId: Number(router.query.userId),
    tagIds: context.query.tagIds,
  }})
  return { props: { data: data.data.userDetails } }
}

export default Page
```

You can read more about the `context` parameter of the `getServerSideProps` here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter